# How to Implement AWS Redis Session in Angular app

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, redis, session-state, elastic-cache

I want to implement AWS redis session in Angular app to store login token in session key that can be used across pods,
I am using sessionStorage currently but need to use AWS redis session
Can anyone please suggest how to do that?

Comment: How is the backend stack looking? Do you have a server-side API? in what language? What web-framework? What compute are you using?

Comment: @Allan Chua I have backend in Java

Answer (score 0):

Sample Java code to connect to Elasticache can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/AutoDiscovery.Using.ModifyApp.Java.html It shows how to use Memcache but you can modify the code to use Redis as per your needs.

As far as the Angular is concerned. Generally Redis is not used with frontend technologies. Redis is used as cache layer for DB or other integrations. You can use to cache the API calls data by your Angular application.

Comment: Thanks @Hussain but I want to use redis in angular as sessionStorage not for cache

Comment: how do you create sessions in your angular app? Where do you store them now?

Comment: I am using windows.session.setItem("key":"value");

Comment: This is the browser session. I'm referring to backend user (authentication) session. It looks like that you're confused about few things. Please read about backend vs frontend technologies